# How to include files while compiling?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to compile a python script to an exe, but before I do that I want to obfuscate it using pyarmor, I fired up pyarmor web ui using `pyarmor-webui` and created a build that gives out a file named the same one as the file I want to compile but obfuscated and a folder containing two files `__init__.py` and `_pytransform.dll` now when I try to compile the obfuscated code into an exe using `pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py` I get an executable that when I run from a batchfile to look at the output it throws the following error  `Could not find "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI72482\pytransform\platforms\windows\x86_64\_pytransform.dll"`

myfile.py

```
import os 
import random 

for i in range (10):
    print (random.randrange(1,100))
```

Batch file

```
try_01.exe
pause
```

How and what do I need to add to pyinstaller command so that it includes the `.dll` file in the compilation process

Comment: Have you tried searching for answers by goggling for, for example _pyinstaller add dll_ - there may be other simple searches which will return useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) say the following:

> --add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
>
> Additional binary files to be added to the executable. See the --add-data option for more details. This option can be used multiple times.

I haven't used pyarmor+pyinstaller before but it should be as simple as:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py --add-binary _pytransform.dll
```

Or, since I looked more into pyarmor's output, it may be:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py _pytransform.dll
```

Comment: I get another error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte`